# c#.net win app sql query

Tags: sql

I am creating windows application.i want to show report of total sales of products in between two dates. i tried the following query to select data but it is not displaying distinct data. my query is:

```
SELECT Distinct(Item_Name),count(Quantity), sum(Amount) 
FROM Product_Table 
GROUP BY Item_Name, Date 
WHERE (Date BETWEEN fromDate AND toDate);
```

thanks

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function (on a column), it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` - and works on the whole selected rows. So skip those redundant parentheses and write `SELECT DISTINCT Item_Name, ...` instead to make code clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong, and should result with an error message for Incorrect syntax.
The `where` clause should come before the `group by` clause and the `distinct` is a keyword, not a function, and it's row wide.
Try this query instead:

```
SELECT Item_Name, Date, count(Quantity), sum(Amount) 
FROM Product_Table 
WHERE (Date BETWEEN fromDate AND toDate)
GROUP BY Item_Name, Date;
```

Comment: In that case, you should mark the answer as accepted so that other people will know that the problem is solved.